# How to build a function that appends to preexisting dataframe in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, append

I am trying use R to build a function that takes an emoji (x) and counts how many times that emoji appears in text data in a vector (txt_vec). I want the output to be appended to a preexisting df (emoji_count). I come from a python background and started recently learning R. Here is what I have tried.

```
emoji_count<- data.frame(Emoji = character(), Count = numeric())
count_emoji<- function(x){
          count = 0
          for (i in 1:length(txt_vec[,])){
                  if(grepl(x, txt_vec[i,])){
                          count = count + 1}}
          a = x
          b = count
          de <- data.frame(a,b)
          names(de)<- c("Emoji", "Count")
          emoji_count<- rbind(emoji_count, de)
}
count_emoji("❤️")
print(emoji_count)
[1] Emoji Count
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

as you can see, the df returns empty. 
I have inspected the vector, which seems to be fine and iterable. After running this line by line the problem seems to be the last line of count_emoji(). If I remove that line and simply print (de), it returns correctly.

```
emoji_count<- data.frame(Emoji = character(), Count = numeric())
> count_emoji<- function(x){
     count = 0
     for (i in 1:length(txt_vec[,])){
         if(grepl(x, txt_vec[i,])){
             count = count + 1}}
     a = x
     b = count
     de <- data.frame(a,b)
     print(de)
}
count_emoji("❤️")
                 a   b
1 <U+2764><U+FE0F> 564
```

I inspected the txt data in a word document and confirmed that it is counting the hearts correctly.The issue is simple trying to join the data frames together. I have also tried having a, b append to vectors to join later using append(y,a), but that also did not work. I am sure the problem is that I am trying to apply python logic to R, so if you could help me understand why this wont append to the emoji_count data frame and how to do this correctly, I would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to assign the returned value from this function call `count_emoji("❤️")` to a variable.  Just calling the function will not necessarily update the underlying variables.

Comment: BTW, it'd be better to add  `text_vec` in your reprex.